# Приложение - будучи или в качестве?

Tags: синтаксис

Приложение с союзом как обычно имеет дополнительное значение причинности (можно заменить придаточным причины с союзами так как, потому что, поскольку или оборотом со словом будучи) и обособляется:

Как старый артиллерист, я презираю этот вид холодного оружия (Шолохов). – Будучи старым артиллеристом, я презираю этот вид холодного оружия; Я презираю этот вид холодного оружия, потому что я старый артиллерист.

Мой друг, как лучший математик класса, будет участником олимпиады.

Мой друг как лучший математик класса будет участником олимпиады.

Здесь постановка запятых зависит от интонации?

Я, как лучший математик класса, буду участником олимпиады.

Я как лучший математик класса буду участником олимпиады.

оба эти варианта возможны в зависимости от интонации?

Или если определяемое слово - местоимение, то обязательно выделять запятыми приложение?

Answer (score 6):

Обособление - это выделение в устной речи интонационно, а в письменной речи - с помощью знаков препинания. И то, и другое в данном случае зависит от смысла, который вы вкладываете во фразу. Правильные знаки помогают читающему понять суть.

Answer (score 2):

Любое приложение при личном местоимении обособляется, и прочитать вы его сможете только с интонацией выделения. Так что вариантов нет:Я, как лучший математик класса, буду участником олимпиады. А значение у приложения явно причинное.

Мой друг, как лучший математик класса, будет участником олимпиады. - тоже без вариантов, потому что другого значения, кроме причинного, здесь нет. Так как он лучший математик, поэтому и будет участником олимпиады.